# why float values are getting store differently in mysql 5.1 and mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, floating-point

'm inserting records in mysql 5.7 where one of the column type is float.

```
mysql 5.7> desc TEST_1;
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| rt_float  | float    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| start     | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+-------+------+-----+---------+-------+
INSERT INTO test_1(rt_float,start) VALUES ('9159573.0000','2016-12-29 00:00:00'),('5335802.8571', '2016-12-29 00:00:00');
```

after selecting the data from data it is rounding off.

```
mysql 5.7> SELECT * FROM test_1;
+----------+--------------------+
| rt_float |  start    
+----------+-------------------+
| 9159570  | 2016-12-29 11:00:00 
| 5335800  | 2016-12-29 12:00:00 
+----------+-------------------+
```

where as if i'm doing the same operation in mysql 5.1 it is giving me correct output as shown.

```
mysql 5.1> desc TEST_1;
+--------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| rt_float     | float    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| start        | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+

INSERT INTO test_1(rt_float,start) VALUES ('9159573.0000','2016-12-29 00:00:00'),('5335802.8571', '2016-12-29 00:00:00');
mysql 5.1> SELECT * FROM test_1;

+--------------+---------------------+
| rt_float     |  start              |
+--------------+---------------------+
| 9.15957e+06  | 2016-12-29 11:00:00 | 
| 5.3358e+06   | 2016-12-29 12:00:00 |
+--------------+---------------------+
```

can some one please help to understanding why it is rounding the number in 5.7 and how can i fix this in 5.7 to get the same output as 5.1.

Comment: The link may not be an exact duplicate, but the basic idea is that float is not exact in MySQL (nor in many other programming language).  Use something like `DECIMAL` instead if you need exact storage.

Comment: the post "Float not correct in MySQL is 8 years old. i'm using the same query in 5.1 works correctly where one of the column type is float where as in 5.7 the same query rounding off the data" can someone tell me why it is happening ?

Comment: I don't have a link, but the safe thing would be to just use `DECIMAL` instead of float.